# Create new column in Pandas dataframe based on latest value per ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have `df` below which I have sorted according to the `ID`variable and the time variable `T` as the secondary sort.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'b'],
    'T': [
        datetime.datetime(2019, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2017, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2018, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1),
        datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 1)],
    'V': [3, 5, 8, 6, 1]
}).sort_values(['ID', 'T'], ascending=False)

df

    ID  T           V
2   c   2018-01-01  8
4   b   2021-01-01  1
3   b   2020-01-01  6
1   b   2017-01-01  5
0   a   2019-01-01  3
```

I want to add a new column `V_L` where, for each `ID`, the last value (based on the time column `T`) is shown. If there is no last value this should be indicated by a `null` value in `V_L`. An example output would look like this:

```
df
    ID  T           V   V_L
0   a   2018-01-01  8   NaN
1   b   2021-01-01  1   6.0
2   b   2020-01-01  6   5.0
3   b   2017-01-01  5   NaN
4   c   2019-01-01  3   NaN
```

Comment: `df['V_L'] = df.groupby('ID')['V'].shift(-1)`

Comment: How have your IDs gone into ascending order there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC

```
df['V_L'] = df.groupby('ID').V.shift(-1)
df
Out[350]: 
  ID           T  V  V_L
2  c  2018-01-01  8  NaN
4  b  2021-01-01  1  6.0
3  b  2020-01-01  6  5.0
1  b  2017-01-01  5  NaN
0  a  2019-01-01  3  NaN
```